# How to add 1 to existing column in a table

Tags: sql, database

Given a table column, say 'RollNumber', how to increment the value of RollNumber by 1 for all the rows ?

Comment: Hint: `UPDATE` ...

Answer (score 1):

Just update your table as:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET RollNumber = RollNumber + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

step-1 : create sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Step-2 : update :

```
update tableName set RollNumber = id.nextval;
```